# More SMTP issues

Tags: email, smtp

Alright -- more SMTP issues. I've looked at some other posts and solutions but so far nothing is working for me.

The login itself has been tested on a separate email client, so we know it works. Here are our config values:

```
$config['mail_protocol'] = 'smtp';
// $config['smtp_server'] = 'ssl://mail.xxxxxxx.net'; <- tried both with and w/o ssl://
$config['smtp_server'] = 'mail.xxxxxxx.net';
$config['smtp_port'] = 995;
$config['email_smtp_port'] = 995;
$config['smtp_username'] = 'xxxx';
$config['smtp_password'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';
$config['email_newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['email_crlf'] = "\r\n";
```

The error message is quite long, but here's a screenshot: http://downloads.creat-ee.com/zisc/ig_email_error.png

Is the issue on the server side? When using PHP protocol, EE says email has been sent but not received either.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP error you posted indicates that mail.[the domain you apparently want redacted].net isn't reachable; your mail settings need to be double-checked - I can't ping that domain either. It's possible that there's a firewall blocking your IP, or that you simply have incorrect settings.

Comment: Thanks Nick -- based on your feedback I'm double-checking everything with our client. I'll come back and update when I find out more. Much appreciate you taking a look!